# How do I get JS popup to position on Load? On Resize works

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I created a simple popup in jQuery, and almost everything seems to work fine except for the on load in the `infoPopupLoadResize()` function. I'm not sure why it isn't firing on page load, but does work on resize.

The purpose of the `infoPopupLoadResize()` function is to calculate the width and height of the popup, and then apply a negative top margin and negative left margin to center the position.

Could it perhaps be a timing issue? I tried using `setTimeout` for calling the function `infoPopupOpen()` to make sure the popup was loaded on the page to call `infoPopupLoadResize()` before opening the popup, but that didn't seem to work either.

**Here is a JSFiddle of my work:** https://jsfiddle.net/pegues/x4qgkLez/

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.triggerpopup').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            infoPopupInit('info','Test<br/>Test<br/>Test');
        });

});



/**
 * Information Popup Initialize Function
 */
function infoPopupInit(type,message){

    // Call Popup Struction
    infoPopup(type,message);

    // Call Popup Controls
    infoPopupControls();

    // Call Popup Load and Resize
    infoPopupLoadResize();

    // Call Popup Open
    infoPopupOpen();
}



/**
 * Information Popup Structure Function
 */
function infoPopup(type,message){

    // HTML Structure
    var popupHintMarkup = 
        '<div class="infopopupbackdrop"></div>' +
        '<div class="infopopup ' + type + '">' +
            '<div class="infopopup_inner">' +
                '<a href="#" class="infopopupclose">x</a>' +
                '<div class="">' +

                    message + 

                    '<div class="clear"></div>' +
                '</div>' +

                '<div class="clear"></div>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="clear"></div>' +
        '</div>';

    // Prepend to Body
    $('body').prepend(popupHintMarkup);
}



/**
 * Information Popup Controls Function
 */
function infoPopupControls(){

    $('.infopopupbackdrop,.infopopupclose').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        infoPopupClose();
    });

}



/**
 * Information Popup Controls Function: Close
 */
function infoPopupClose(){
    $('.infopopupbackdrop').delay(50).fadeOut(150);
    $('.infopopup').fadeOut(150);

    // Remove Popup after 300ms
    var closePopup = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.infopopupbackdrop,.infopopup').remove();
    },300);
}



/**
 * Information Popup Controls Function: Open
 */
function infoPopupOpen(){
    $('.infopopup').delay(50).fadeIn(150);;
    $('.infopopupbackdrop').fadeIn(150);
}



/**
 * Information Popup Load/Resize Function
 */
function infoPopupLoadResize(){

    // On Load and Resize
    $(window).on('load resize', function(){

        var _Width = $('.infopopup').width();
        var _Height = $('.infopopup').height();

        console.log('Width: ' + _Width + ' Height: ' + _Height);

        $('.infopopup').css({ marginTop: -(_Height/2), marginLeft: -(_Width/2) });
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="triggerpopup" style="margin: 15px;padding: 0 15px;display: block;float: left;height: 35px;color: #fff;font: 13px/35px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;text-decoration: none;background-color: #b33;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px;">Open Popup</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Information Popup Backdrop */
div.infopopupbackdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 998;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    }



/* Information Popup Content */
div.infopopup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    box-shadow:         0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    }
    div.infopopup_inner {
        position: relative;
        padding: 25px;
        border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
        background-color: #fff;

        -webkit-border-radius:  5px;
        -moz-border-radius:     5px;
        border-radius:          5px;
        }
        a.infopopupclose {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            display: block;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
```

Window load has happened a little while ago as window is not your popup but the browser window.

You can fix this by always executing this function when your popup is being opened

```
/**
 * Information Popup Load/Resize Function
 */
function infoPopupLoadResize(){
    var _Width = $('.infopopup').width();
    var _Height = $('.infopopup').height();

    console.log('Width: ' + _Width + ' Height: ' + _Height);

    $('.infopopup').css({ marginTop: -(_Height/2), marginLeft: -(_Width/2)});
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Information Popup Initialize Function
 */
function infoPopupInit(type,message){

    // Call Popup Struction
    infoPopup(type,message);

    // Call Popup Controls
    infoPopupControls();

    // Call Popup Load and Resize
    infoPopupLoadResize();
    $(window).on('resize', infoPopupLoadResize);

    // Call Popup Open
    infoPopupOpen();
}
```

Comment: I tested it out and it works great. Thank you @hansgoed. What you provided as the solution makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You try to get information when the window is load or resize, ok but before you need to check if the popup is open, i just modify the last function :

JS :

```
function infoPopupLoadResize(){

    // On Load and Resize
    $(infoPopupOpen).ready(function(){

        var _Width = $('.infopopup').width();
        var _Height = $('.infopopup').height();

        console.log('Width: ' + _Width + ' Height: ' + _Height);

        $('.infopopup').css({ marginTop: -(_Height/2), marginLeft: -(_Width/2) });
    });
}
```

After, you can check if the window is resize :)

The jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/AnTSaSk/gz13rLs7/

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution @AnTSaSk.